# Turning Row values into separate columns in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data-set that pulls the variables of interest but arranges them in rows when ideally they would be in separate columns. It looks like this

`GEOID   NAME        VARIABLE     VALUE
    00601   ZCTA5 00601 PCT023003   17285
2   00601   ZCTA5 00601 PCT023004   572
3   00601   ZCTA5 00601 PCT023006   5
4   00601   ZCTA5 00601 P004001 18570
5   00602   ZCTA5 00602 PCT023003   35980
6   00602   ZCTA5 00602 PCT023004   2210
7   00602   ZCTA5 00602 PCT023006   22
8   00602   ZCTA5 00602 P004001 41520`

and I'd like to have the 4 variables represent 4 columns all tied to the unique ZCTA5 value. How can i transform the data to fit that description. Sorry for poor wording.

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of the example and expecte doutput

Comment: I would like a new set of columns titled (PCT0230023, PCT023004, etc) with their associated values represented in the value columns

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df1, names_from = VARIABLE, values_from = VALUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  GEOID NAME        PCT023003 PCT023004 PCT023006 P004001
#  <int> <chr>           <int>     <int>     <int>   <int>
#1   601 ZCTA5 00601     17285       572         5   18570
#2   602 ZCTA5 00602     35980      2210        22   41520
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(GEOID = c(601L, 601L, 601L, 601L, 602L, 602L, 
602L, 602L), NAME = c("ZCTA5 00601", "ZCTA5 00601", "ZCTA5 00601", 
"ZCTA5 00601", "ZCTA5 00602", "ZCTA5 00602", "ZCTA5 00602", "ZCTA5 00602"
), VARIABLE = c("PCT023003", "PCT023004", "PCT023006", "P004001", 
"PCT023003", "PCT023004", "PCT023006", "P004001"), VALUE = c(17285L, 
572L, 5L, 18570L, 35980L, 2210L, 22L, 41520L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```